# Mobile styling error occurring

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I have the following code which genereates a mobile styling error (see picture 1):

```
<div class="left">
   <p>Ditt namn (obligatorisk)<br />                          
     [text* your-name]</p>
   <p>Din epost (obligatorisk)<br />
     [email* your-email] </p>
   <p>Ditt telefonnummer<br />
     [tel tel-621] </p>
   <p>Ämne<br />
     [select menu-101 include_blank "Konstruktions ritningar" "Visualisering" "Mjukvara utveckling" "Övrigt"]</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <p>Ditt meddelande<br />
     [textarea your-message] </p>
 </div>
 <p>[submit "Skicka"]</p
```

The css is like this:

```
.left, .right {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:45%;}
```

On the website it looks good:

URL: http://byggprojektoren.se/kontaktaoss/

Picture of mobile version;

[image: Picture 1]

I am really confused on how to fix this since it seems like Ive tried everything. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: you should add all the relevant code to your answer and possibly provide a fiddle

Comment: `.left, .right {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; min-width:45%;}`

Comment: @Luca I have not solved the issue yet.

Comment: @Pye The code you pasted is the same as mine?

Comment: @RinorM `min-width` instead of `width`

Comment: @Pye sorry for missing that one. I tried your solution and it worked very good. Thumbs up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add some media queries. Heres a starter for you:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .right {
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .right textarea {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of these components should I adjust for the mobile site to be corrected?

Comment: just copy the whole block, it should sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bootstraps or foundation grid system?
The problem here seems to be that you have width of 45% and elements are just squeezed on top of eachother.

Comment: Hi, I am kind of new to this and have never tried using bootstraps or foundation grid system. I will try adjusting the width a bit more.

Comment: If you want it to work on both mobile and desktop, then you should have a look at one of those, they have really nice examples, and then after you get a hand of it, you can start creating your own grid with media queries.

May this be a starter for you in using bootstrap: http://www.bootply.com/Bwv4FpYEXS

Comment: thank you. But I am really not sure on how to implement that to my issue?

Comment: add col-sm-6 col-xs-12 classes to elements which have left and right class, and put both of them to a div which a class row. Dont forget to download and add bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code works as expected but the content of .left and .right overflows the container.
If you add width: 100% and box-sizing: border-box on inputs & textarea, their size will adapt correctly.

```
input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Hi, do I add this in the css along with the .left and .right?

Comment: What do you mean by new rule :) ?

Comment: .left, .right {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:45%;}
input, textarea {width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}